# Microsoft Enhanced redirection security with OWIN/MVC5 auth

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am setting up Microsoft authentication for a site built off the MVC5 default template.

I've enabled MS authentication in `Startup.Auth.cs` and gotten tokens from MS, however it only seems to work when I have `Enhanced redirection security` off (which sounds like a good thing to enable).

[image]

I think i must have the redirect URL wrong as I get the following with Enhanced redirection security on. **What is the correct redirect URL to use based on the default MVC5 template?**

i have tried the following:

- http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Account/ExternalLogin
  http://mysite.azurewebsites.net/Account/ExternalLoginCallback

[image]

Comment: `ExternalLogin` is what *your* code should reference.  `ExternalLoginCallback` is what the OAuth provider will call back when it has completed its authorization check.

Comment: @Dan-o that makes sense but neither seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the Katana MW uses your app's base path + "/signin-microsoft" as the callback URL. Try plugging that into the Live admin tool and enabling the enhanced redirection.

Comment: Works perfectly much appreciated :) its a shame its not more discoverable though

Comment: Apparently open source is also now documentation. Yes, it's a shame.